# getting 'OCR runtime error' while getting scanned document text using OCR

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get text from scanned document.but i am getting error 'OCR Runtime error'. i also make changes in my web.config for large document...if you have any solution then please help me out...Thank you all in advance.

```
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxRequestLength="200000"
  executionTimeout="999999" requestLengthDiskThreshold="200000"/>
```

below is my code behind snippet:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(filePath);
        string extractText = this.ExtractTextFromImage(filePath);
        string[] lines = extractText.Split(
        new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
        StringSplitOptions.None
        );
       Label1.Text = extractText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");

        var FirstName = lines[2].ToString();
        var FatherName = lines[3].ToString();
        var DOB =        lines[4].ToString();
        var PermenantAccountNumber = lines[6].ToString();


    string s = DOB;
        string t = "/";
        s = s.Remove(2, t.Length);
        s = s.Insert(2, t);
        var DateOfBirth = s;

        boObj.FirstName = FirstName;
        boObj.MiddleName = FatherName;
        boObj.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;
        boObj.AccountNumber = PermenantAccountNumber;
        blObj.SubmitBAL(boObj);
    }
 private string ExtractTextFromImage(string filePath)
    {
        Document modiDocument1 = new Document();
        modiDocument1.Create(filePath);

        modiDocument1.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_ENGLISH);  //Getting Error here

        MODI.Image modiImage = (modiDocument1.Images[0] as MODI.Image);
        string extractedText = modiImage.Layout.Text;
        modiDocument1.Close();
        return extractedText;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and limit it to include relevant code only, 90% of it is unneeded and only will cause people to skip the question. The error text you show is as meaningless to us as it is to you. Please provide details: (1) Did you check the `InnerException` object, what does it say? (2) What is the exact type of `Document`? (3) Which OCR software are you using?

Comment: Hey peter...Greetings....1)In inner exception it showing 'NULL' 2).i am trying to access text of image(.jpg) scan document 3)Microsoft Office Document Imaging 12.0 ..This is  OCR  software which i am using...waiting for positive response.